# In the sentence "The table was set for lunch" is "set" a verb or an adjective?

Tags: passive-voice, ambiguity, past-participles, parsing, active-vs-passive

> *The table was set for lunch*

I want to see if this is a passive sentence. I think if the word "set" is a verb it is passive, but if “set” is an adjective it would be an active one.

Comment: Honestly I can make my brain read it either way. "The table was set for lunch by the waitress": definitely a verb, since there's someone doing the setting. "The table was set for lunch, and the plates were shiny and clean": parallelism suggests reading it as an adjective to match the adjectives in the second clause.

Comment: The table *is new/ laid/  ready/  bare/ set* ...

Comment: What practical problem are you trying to find the solution to here? What would you do with an answer to this question? Is there a real-world use-case where that grammatical answer makes some difference in syntax or meaning or focus you'd use or imply when writing or speaking about it? For example, do you want "a set(-up) table", or are you perhaps more interested in finding a table with "a lunch setup" than in finding the actual people who had "set the table" for lunch?

Comment: If "set" is an adjective, then I don't think it makes sense in English to ascribe either a passive or active mood to the copula "was".

Comment: "was set" is a periphrastic construction to "conjugate" the verb "to set" in the passive mood.

Answer (score 23):

As is, there is not enough information to be able to tell, definitively.

i.e. The answer depends on the context in which the sentence appears.

If, for example, it were to be preceded by "I looked into the dining room. The table was set for lunch." then it is an adjective, describing the state of the table.

But if it were surrounded by "We drove home from the supermarket. The table was set for lunch. A grand repast was enjoyed by all." then it would be a verb, describing what was done to the table.

Comment: Sorry, this is mistaken. [correction: adective?]

Comment: I find the second example to still be ambiguous - it either implies that everyone arrived home from the supermarket to find the table already set, or that someone set the table after everyone got home (verb). Following the active voice with a passive voice action done by the same people strikes me as odd. It might be more clear with a lead-in that makes it obvious that the table being set is not the default, ongoing state - perhaps "The restaurant patrons who had breakfast got up and left. The table was set for lunch. We sat down to eat." This also implies we don't care who set the table.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie It's switching to passive voice for that sentence - like if a scientist wrote in a paper *"The solution was stirred for three minutes"*.  In active voice you would say *"I stirred the solution for three minutes"*, or in this case *"We set the table for lunch"*, meaning the group took action to make the table ready for lunch.  In the first example it is not passive voice - it's in the past tense, simply making the observation that the state of the table was already "set for lunch" - no action takes place.

Comment: Another example would be *"I saw James in the doorway - he was dressed for a night out"*.  Here like the first case, making an observation on the state of James' outfit.  This is different from *"James came home and was dressed for a night out by his butler."* - here the butler is taking an action to dress James in clothes for the evening.

Comment: @J... There's nothing technically wrong with the switch to passive voice, although it seems a little out of place since that's typically used when we don't know or care who did the action. If we're talking about things "we" did (drove home), I find it odd to remove ourselves from other actions also done by "us" (set the table). My example with the restaurant sounds better to my ear as a verb usage, as the passive action is performed by someone who isn't known or mentioned at all (a nameless waiter), rather than already-mentioned people who have previously been described in the active voice.

Comment: Yes. I knew it wasn't perfect when I wrote it (I was overexcited at finding a question I could answer) but it didn't affect the point I was trying to make, which was that "set" in the original isolated sentence could not be nailed down as being either an adjective or a verb because the meaning of the sentence was ambiguous without further clarification.

Comment: As per @Lambie's answer, _"...Past participles can all be used as adjectives..."_ - and that's what's happening here.  It's not correct to say that we don't have enough information to determine whether this is a verb or an adjective.  We know exactly what it is.  It's the past participle of a verb.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thanks, I can only conclude there is a basic misunderstanding of grammar here.

Comment: Per the OED: "A participial adjective is an adjective that is derived from, and identical in form with, a present participle or a past participle. It is often difficult to draw a distinction between participial adjectives and the participles from which they are derived. Earlier editions of the OED treated participial adjectives as a separate part of speech from other adjectives, but in the revised edition *such words are treated as adjectives*.
https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/glossary-grammatical-terms/#participial-adjective

Answer (score 9):

A verb, a past participle and a passive construction seem to be a reasonable analysis.

As a participle, we could ask for the active form and would get "Someone set the table for lunch."  That seems valid. We can add a "by" phrase "The table was set for lunch by Joe".  That also seems valid.

If it were an adjective we might ask "how set was it"? We might be able to modify the word with "quite" or "more", use the word attributively, or use the word with other linking verbs:  "The table was more set" seems wrong.  "There was a set table." Perhaps, but not very natural.  "The table seemed set for lunch" :- No you'd say "seemed to be set..."

So describing the word "set" as a verb and a participle fits best here. The grammatical subject "Table" is semantically the object.

Comment: Your argument against it being an adjective makes no sense. While all adjectives may be qualified by adverbs, they needn't have a matter of degree; one can't be _very_ dead, but one could say the table was _recently_ set.

Comment: I think that example isn't the best. While figurative, one can definitely say someone's *very* dead (obviously, definitely, completely sure that that person is dead). I am drawing a blank right now, trying to come up with an adjective that breaks this pattern, but that's probably not really indicative of anything.

Comment: "Is the table set or not?"

Answer (score 7):

Let's **set the table for dinner**. [i.e. put out forks, knives, spoons, glasses, plates, etc.]

[A Mother says] I usually set the table for dinner but sometimes my kids do. It is set by them.

[To father;] **Was** the table **set** last night [by the kids] when you got home?

was set is the passive form of the verb set.

Reasoning:
The table was set. [by the kids]

Compare that to:
The job was finished. [by the plumber]
The dog was found. [by the volunteers]

**Those are all action or active verbs used passively**.

**Past participles can all be used as adjectives**:

- The set table was so beautiful to see.
- The finished job looked great!
- The found dog was not the lost dog.

The past participles are, respectively, set, finished and found.

The principal parts of the verb set are: set, set, set. It's unchangeable.

In order to answer this question, it was useful to write other similar utterances and compare them. The result shows that **set** is a verb.

Answer (score 5):

> *The table was set for lunch.*

"Set" is ambiguous here between an adjective and a verb.

If it describes a state resulting from a prior action then it's an adjective in a complex intransitive clause.

But if it describes an event then it's a verb in a *be* passive clause. Note the possibility of adding a *by* phrase: *The table was quickly set for lunch by the waitress.*

Comment: "quite set"?  "more set" -  Does this pass your tests for adjectives?

Comment: @JamesK Those tests are possible in the right context, but a better test is the replacement of "be" by "remain" or "seem": in "The table remained/seemed set for lunch" "set" is clearly adjectival.

Comment: @JamesKj what about: "The table was **almost/nearly set**": i.e *ready* Wouldn't "set", in this case, be classed as an adjective?

Answer (score 1):

The sentences "the table is being set for dinner" and "the table is set for dinner" would both be written in a past tense form as "the table was set for dinner".  The first form of the sentence clearly uses "set" as a verb in a passive construct, while the second uses "set" as an adjective.  The past-tense form could thus use the word "set" as either a verb or adjective, depending upon whether is a past-tense form of the first or second sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The word "set" can be an adjective, but I feel that that applies more to people. "I'm all set to go on vacation." Contrary to James K, I think that this can take comparatives: "I'm more set to go on vacation that you."

So I find the past participle sense stronger, but the adjective sense is not impossible.

Comment: When talking of a "meal table", "set" for many people is an alternative to "lay" that can be used adjectivally: Expressions like _The table looks nicely set/laid for lunch_ are common enough.

Answer (score 0):

"Was set" is a verb.

Don't think of it as two verbs, "was" and "set".*  Think of it as one verb, "was set".  This is past tense, passive voice for "set".

---

*- (Technically, it's two verbs, which are used together to make one verb.  But it's ***mainly*** one verb, not two.)